# How to communicate ReactDOM.render with other ReactDOM.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I have a project that includes React applications and other HTML elements.
It means:

`ReactDOM.render(<Element1/>, document.getElementById('element1')
<some section with HTML />
ReactDOM.render(<Element2/>, document.getElementById('element2')`

The problem is to pass a variable/props/state from one ReactDOM.render to the other.

How can I do this?

I am currently using the global variable `window`, but after changing it does not refresh the data in the second ReactDOM.render.

Comment: You have XY problem. If these are two unrelated widgets, it's unnecessary that they should be rendered with ReactDOM.render. They could be portals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for two React components to efficiently communicate by means of React alone, they should communicate through common parent.

In case of two unrelated widgets, they can be rendered as portals with a common parent, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52408076/3731501):

```
<div id="App"></div>
<h2>Foo widget</h2>
<div id="FooWidget"></div>
<h2>Bar widget</h2>
<div id="BarWidget"></div>
```

---

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    state = {
      foo: 'foo',
      setFoo(foo) {
        this.setState(state => ({...state, foo}));
      }
    };

    return <FoobarContext.Provider value={this.state}>    
      {ReactDOM.createPortal(<FooWidget />, document.getElementById('FooWidget'))} 
      {ReactDOM.createPortal(<BarWidget />, document.getElementById('BarWidget'))} 
    </FoobarContext.Provider>;
  }
}

const FooWidget = props => <FoobarContext.Consumer>
  {({ foo }) => foo}
</FoobarContext.Consumer>;

...

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('App'));
```

Components can communicate through `foo` context property by using `setFoo` setter.

An alternative that can make use of `ReactDOM.render` is to use Redux and connect two unrelated components to same store. They can communicate through common store.

Answer (score 1):

You would have various option like subscribing to events between the app:

```js
// App #1
const event = new Event('start');
// Dispatch the event.
elem.dispatchEvent(event);


// App #2 Listen for the event.
componentDidMount() {
  elem.addEventListener('start', this.start }, false);
}

start = (e) => {
  // ....
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  elem.removeEventListener('start');
}
```

The point anyway is you should use a global store like Redux picking component you need from both apps as this kind of solution are very diffucult to maintain.