# How would I restructure my React App, so that I can pass state down to a component on a different route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three components routed to different paths. I want to restructure my App so that I can pass state via props from my `SubmitProject` Component to my `Portfolio` Component I still want them to have separate paths ie; `/portfolio` and `/SubmitProject` I plan to have two browserwindows open to test that when I submit a form on `SubmitProject` it will show up on `Portfolio` then I will be using firebase to persist my state to a database.

Do I need to have my state be at a top level Component like `App.js` and then have the `BrowserRouter` inside of that? If so how do I recreate the connections I have made from `<SubmitProject/>` -> `<PortfolioForm/>` -> `<FormAdd/>`

My Desired Goal is that when I submit the form from the `FormAdd` Component when I am on the `/submit` Route that it will output via state on my `Portfolio` Component on the `/Portfolio` Route.

It has been recommend to use a state manager like context api, or something else, but I want to know if there is a way to restructure my App and be able to pass state from a top level component that each component and route share.

Here is my relevant code

**`components/Router.js`**

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Portfolio from './Portfolio';
import SubmitProject from './SubmitProject';
import App from './App';

const Router = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
            <Route exact path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio}/>
            <Route exact path="/submit" component={SubmitProject}/>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Router;
```

**`components/App.js` // Should My Router be in here?**

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
      return <div>Test</div>
  }

}

export default App;
```

**`/components/SubmitProject.js`**

```
import React from 'react';
import PortfolioForm from './PortfolioForm';
import Section from './Section';

class SubmitProject extends React.Component {
    state = {
        sections:{}
    };
    addSection = section =>{
        const sections = {...this.state.sections};
        sections[`section${Date.now()}`] = section;
        this.setState({
            sections: sections
        });
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1>Submit Project</h1>
                <h2>Enter Project Data</h2>
                <ul className="section">
                    {Object.keys(this.state.sections).map(key => <Section key={key} details={this.state.sections[key]}/>)}
                </ul>
                <PortfolioForm addSection={this.addSection} />
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default SubmitProject;
```

**`/components/PortfolioForm.js`**

```
import React from 'react';
import FormAdd from './FormAdd';

class Portfolio extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1>Submit Form</h1>
                <FormAdd addSection={this.props.addSection}/>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default Portfolio;
```

**`/components/FormAdd.js`**

```
import React from 'react';

class FormAdd extends React.Component {
    nameRef = React.createRef();

    createSection = (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        const section = {
            name: this.nameRef.current.value
        };
        this.props.addSection(section);
    };  
    render() {
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <form onSubmit={this.createSection}>
                    <input type="text" ref={this.nameRef} name="name" placeholder="Name"/>
                    <button type="submit">+ Add Section</button>
                </form>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default FormAdd;
```

**`/components/Portfolio.js`**

```
import React from 'react';

class Portfolio extends React.Component {
    //CAN I GET STATE FROM SubmitProject.js FILE IN HERE? By Restructuring my App Somehow.
    render() {
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1>Portfolio Page</h1>
                <h2>List of projects</h2>     
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default Portfolio;
```

**UPDATED CODE**
I am now getting an error that says `FooContext is not defined`

`components/App.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import SubmitProject from './SubmitProject';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

const FooContext = React.createContext();

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    sections:{}
  };
  addSection = section =>{
      const sections = {...this.state.sections};
      sections[`section${Date.now()}`] = section;
      this.setState({
          sections: sections
      });
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <FooContext.Provider value={this.state.sections}>
          <Router/>;
        </FooContext.Provider>
      )
  }

}

class Router extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return 
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Root} />      
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  }
}

const Root = props => <FooContext.Consumer>{sections => <SubmitProject/> }</FooContext.Consumer>;

export default App;
```

**UPDATED CODE V#2**
`App.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import SubmitProject from './SubmitProject';
import Home from './Home';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

const FooContext = React.createContext();

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    sections:{}
  };
  addSection = section =>{
      const sections = {...this.state.sections};
      sections[`section${Date.now()}`] = section;
      this.setState({
          sections: sections
      });
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <FooContext.Provider value={this.state.sections}>
          <Router/>;
        </FooContext.Provider>
      )
  }

}

class Router extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} /> 
            <Route exact path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />      
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter> 
    )

  }
}

const Portfolio = props => <FooContext.Consumer>{foo => <SubmitProject/>}</FooContext.Consumer>;

export default App;
```

`SubmitProject.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import PortfolioForm from './PortfolioForm';
import Section from './Section';

class SubmitProject extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return(
                <React.Fragment>
                    <h1>Submit Project</h1>
                    <h2>Enter Project Data</h2>
                    <ul className="section">
                        {Object.keys(this.state.sections).map(key => <Section key={key} details={this.state.sections[key]}/>)}
                    </ul>
                    <PortfolioForm addSection={this.addSection} />
                </React.Fragment>   

        )
    }
}

export default SubmitProject;
```

Comment: So basically you don't have a root component? every route change your entire application is re-rendered.

Comment: Ok yeah so, I should be putting my router Component in my App maybe? And then where do I declare my state? so that it can be passed to all my other components.

Comment: If you have a root component that persist and doesn't remount on every route change (`App` for example) then you can manage a local state in there and pass it as props to its children. Remember, `<Route />` is only a component, you can render it anywhere, you may need to use the `render` prop instead of `component` prop

Comment: Could you possibly show me in code what you mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> It has been recommend to use a state manager like context api, or something else, but I want to know if there is a way to restructure my App and be able to pass state from a top level component that each component and route share.

There are problems with this approach.

Considering that `App` maintains application state, it's necessary to pass it to `<Router>` as a prop and then to route components that depend on it:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { foo: true };

  render() {
      return <Router foo={this.state.foo}/>
  }
}

const Router = props => (
    const RootWithFoo = props => <Root foo={props.foo}/>;

    return <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={RootWithFoo} />
            ...
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

This puts a restriction on component structure; in order to avoid deeply passed props, `Router` component should be removed, and `Route` should be rendered directly in `App`:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { foo: true };

  render() {
    const RootWithFoo = props => <Root foo={this.state.foo}/>;

    return <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={RootWithFoo} />
            ...
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  }
}
```

This is a problem that context API and state management libraries (e.g. Redux) address. They allow to provide global state for nested components where it's used.

Another problem is performance. The whole router will be re-rendered on each state update. Again, context API and state management libraries address this. As [context API manual](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consumer) states:

> All Consumers that are descendants of a Provider will re-render whenever the Provider’s value prop changes. The propagation from Provider to its descendant Consumers is not subject to the shouldComponentUpdate method, so the Consumer is updated even when an ancestor component bails out of the update.

So if context provider value updates, it's unnecessary to re-render the whole tree. Context consumer will be re-rendered regardless of this. Since the whole tree will be re-rendered by default, `Provider` child(ren) should be a pure component to avoid unnecessary re-renders. This is a reason why separated `App` and `Router` components may be preferable:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { foo: true };

  render() {
    return <FooContext.Provider value={this.state.foo}>
      <Router/>;
    </FooContext.Provider>
  }
}

class Router extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Root} />
            ...
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  }
}

const Root = props => <FooContext.Consumer>{foo => ...}</FooContext.Consumer>;
```

When global state is updated, only `App` and route components that depend on it (`Root`, etc.) are re-rendered but not `Router`.

Comment: Are you suggesting I use contextAPI and move my routing into App.js and what do you mean by 'pass it to <route> as a prop' could you possibly give me an example of what that would look like, this is the first react app I have attempted to build so very much a noob

Comment: I've tried to make examples more illustrative. Hope this helps. The way how it's integrated with Firebase is up to you, but I suppose that `App` should listen for Firebase updates and update its state when needed.

Comment: Hey Thanks for making this more illustrative. On the last line what am I supposed to put in the `foo => ...` section and what does it look like to pass state down to the different routers ie; `SubmitProject.js` & `Porfolio.js`

Comment: `...` are the contents of route component that depends on global state (foo). Other route components may look like `Root`. Component contents are wrapped with `<FooContext.Consumer>{foo => ...}</FooContext.Consumer>`. If it's a class then `render` function return value is wrapped with it.

Comment: I have added some new code based on your answer that is giving me an error saying `FooContext is not defined` you can see the updated code above. Thanks

Comment: You need to create it as any other context, e.g. `const FooContext = React.createContext()`. See https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Ok after I do that, I get the following error `TypeError: this.state is null` for my `SubmitPorject.js` page I am not sure if I did the `const Root` part at the bottom correctly you can see in my updated code to see if it is correct

Comment: There should be separate route for SubmitProject, shouldn't it? It was placed into Root as is. If SubmitProject depends on `sections` then this is  the component that should contain `<FooContext.Consumer>`, not Root. You also need to abolish local state in SubmitProject and update `sections` in global state. There should be `addSections` in context. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52661082/3731501 for example (foo and setFoo).

Comment: Check a demo. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tp9bfu . I guess you can sort this out from this point.

Comment: I tried to setup the demo across multiple files like I have it locally. You can view it here https://react-9yu6pt.stackblitz.io I am currently getting a `_a is undefined error`

Comment: The error is `Cannot read property 'sections' of undefined` in editor. You have multiple `const FooContext`. There should be only one, it should be imported in multiple places.