# wrap multiple react DOM component in redux's Provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-dom

I have this code on my `index.js` file in my ReactJS project and I want the redux's `<Provider>` tag to wrap them up so that they can all access the same store, 
 The question is, how can I do that?

```
ReactDOM.render(<Header />, document.getElementById('header'));
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
ReactDOM.render(<Footer />, document.getElementById('footer'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if the `store` is the same, then you can simply apply the `<Provider>` to all pieces and they will all use the same Redux store. The `Provider` is not mandatory to be unique, just the `store`. Something like this:

```
const store = createStore(...); // or any valid Redux store declaration or import

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><Header /></Provider>, document.getElementById('header'));
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><Footer /></Provider>, document.getElementById('footer'));
```

Answer (score 3):

As another answer already suggests, this can be achieved by using same store in Redux provider. Since Redux isn't tied to React component hierarchy, connected components don't necessarily should have a common parent:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}><Header /></Provider>,
  document.getElementById('header')
);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}><Footer /></Provider>,
  document.getElementById('footer')
);
```

Another option that isn't specific to Redux but can also be used with any React application that has several root components is to use portals for these components, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52406415/set-react-context-provider-state-programatically-from-outside-the-tree/52408076#52408076):

```
const Page = props => (
  <Provider store={store}>    
      {ReactDOM.createPortal(<Header/>, document.getElementById('header'))} 
      {ReactDOM.createPortal(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))} 
      {ReactDOM.createPortal(<Footer/>, document.getElementById('footer'))}
  </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Page/>, document.getElementById('page'));
```

Where `<div id="page"></div>` is placeholder element that exists in HTML body to mount the application and doesn't have to be a parent to header, etc. elements.

This option can be used with React context API `Provider` or page component `state` as well.

Comment: shouldn't it have a `return` statement? because I'm having an error saying that `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression` in the line where the provider tag is.

Comment: Notice that there are `=> (...)` parentheses, not `=> {...}` brackets. Brackets require `return`. Parentheses make use of implicit return.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you need to target three html elements? The standard practice here would be to just target `root` and handle the rest in your React application, like below:

In `index.js`:

```
const store = createStore(...);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

In `App.js`:

```
export default = () =>
  <Header />
  <Body />
  <Footer />
```

Your entire HTML body would look like this (recommended approach by Facebook's [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)):

```
<body>
  <noscript>JavaScript must be enabled to run this application.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```