# React 16.6 lazy/Suspense DOM exception

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to enable dynamic import in my React app. Most of React examples renders application to some tag replacing the content, e.g.:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />,  document.getElementById('app'));
```

But I need to keep static block inside `#app` element and rendering React like this:

```
let container = document.createElement('div');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, container);
let app = document.getElementById('app');
app.appendChild(container);
let renderedHeader = container.querySelector('#header');
let renderedWrapper = container.querySelector('#wrapper');
app.querySelector('#header').replaceWith(renderedHeader);
app.querySelector('#wrapper').replaceWith(renderedWrapper);
```

Everything works as expected until I try to use lazy/Suspense components.

Here is ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/vitalyster/a66dda2342734fee78eb988e4c16a6e0)/[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/suspense-error)) the full example which throws
`DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.` inside `Suspense` component.

Is it my issue or Suspense issue?

Is there a more common way to render React app but keep static blocks?

Comment: Why can't the static element just be another React component? That would be the ideal way (don't know if it will solve your problem)

Comment: It should be reached on server in static file by legacy apps

Comment: What do you mean? The content of the static thing is retrieved from the server? If so, use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to load the data into your component after it loads

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Yes, exactly

Comment: No, I can't set HTML in React app, I need to have it there before React, as legacy app does not support javascript

Comment: Consider providing a workable demo that could be debugged at least. Also, a demo hosted at Stackblitz or other service has better chances to survive over time than your own gist.

Comment: Sorry, does not have experience with Stackblitz or "other service", will try to set up it

Comment: @estus added stackblitz link

Comment: I see. That's not Suspense issue, you just don't need to alter DOM manually. `#header`, etc selectors refer to different elements at different moments of time. I'm not sure how exactly the code needs to be refactored in your case but that's a common use for portals. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53557119/wrap-multiple-react-dom-component-in-reduxs-provider or https://stackoverflow.com/a/52408076/3731501 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `#header` and `#wrapper` selectors refer to different elements at different moments of time.

At the moment when `container.querySelector('#header')` is executed, `#header` refers to `<div id="header">` in fallback component (`LoadingView`) that is supposed to be removed from DOM later.

It's preferable to treat `Header` and `Wrapper` as different components and mount them to existing `<div id="header">` and `<div id="wrapper">` placeholders as [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). They can still be nested within parent component (`App` or `Main`) to share state between them.

Comment: Interesting. But createPortal append component to #header as child and did not remove its old content. Am I miss something?

Comment: If that's the only obstacle, you can clear #header contents beforehand to remove `Header template` stuff.

Comment: If i do `document.getelementbyid('header').innerHTML=''` I receive the same DOM exception as before

Comment: Are you doing this with portals? Can you provide a demo of how you're doing that?

Comment: Solved the issue by not providing header in loading component, not needed for me to update header in loading view

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. The problem was that you cleared up #header contents where header portal was already rendered. Since Header shouldn't be aware that it's a portal, you could move `ReactDOM.createPortal` and `innerHTML` to `Main`.